# change AM PM label text in material-ui mobile-date-time-picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change AM | PM | OK | cancel dialog button text?
[image: time picker dialog with altered buttons' text]
https://next.material-ui.com/api/mobile-date-time-picker/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "Cancel" and "OK" - check the page you have linked - there is a `cancelText` and `okText` properties.
Regarding the AM/PM - I dont think there is props for that - consider carefully if you want to change that - its standard around the world.

Comment: hey, inorder to use these properties I needed to set "varient" property to dialog.
I  also changed the direacrion of actionBar by adding property
 DialogProps = {{ style: { color: "red", direction: 'ltr' } }}